# How to point CNAME to Digital Ocean droplet

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, nginx, cname-record

Having an issue trying to point a CNAME to my Digital Ocean droplet

I created a CNAME on DNSimple and pointed it to the IP address of my Digital Ocean droplet: `ironman4x4.adamgeorge.com`

I've tested that it exists:

```
→  ~  host -t cname ironman4x4.adamgeorge.com
ironman4x4.adamgeorge.com is an alias for 128.199.176.45.
```

My Digital Ocean droplet was created using this guide:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-1-click-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-14-04-image

The 1-click install creates a default site here which I tried customising the `root` and `server_name` options:

```
server {
        listen   80;
        root /home/rails/current/public;
        server_name _ ironman4x4.*;
        index index.htm index.html;

        client_max_body_size 5M;

        location / {
                try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
        }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
                        try_files $uri @app;
                }

         location @app {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

}
```

Not sure why it's not working.

I can't SSH onto the server via `ssh root@ironman4x4.adamgeorge.com`,  nor does Nginx respond via http://ironman4x4.adamgeorge.com

Not sure why?

Is there anything else I need to configure for either the DNS or or the droplet to get this to work?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I assume that the downvote is because the voter expects that the target audience of this site know the difference between a CNAME and an A record.

Comment: @mattdm - that's disappointing. I'm a software developer not a sysadmin. I know *some* differences between CNAMES and A records, but I don't know much compared to someone who regularly deals with DNS. Certainly on Stack Overflow we don't downvote people for asking easy programming questions. Maybe I should have asked there instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CNAME` record type makes one name into an alias of another name.

Ie, the value of your `CNAME` record is not an IP address but a name with all-numeric labels.

You probably simply want to create an `A` record instead.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that may have been the case (that I needed to use a A record), but I didn't have a spare domain to play with and thought I would try a CNAME instead. When it didn't work with the CNAME, I wanted to know *why* it didn't work. Since I had pointed CNAMES to external sites before (i.e. Heroku), I just assumed that would work with an external IP address to. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using an A record, not a CNAME.